# Как мне указать путь к файлу в qt на рабочий стол?

Tags: windows, qt, qtcreator, path, desktop

Как мне указать путь к файлу в qt на рабочий стол? При условии, чтобы он открывался на других пк, где имя пользователя будет другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо использовать функцию `QStandardPaths::standardLocations` с аргументом `QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation`

Пример:

```
    QStringList list = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation);
    QString fileName = list.first() + '/' + "names.ini";
```

Comment: Вот допустим у меня есть вот такая часть кода `name = new QSettings("d:/Результаты/names.ini", QSettings::IniFormat, this);` . Как мне здесь использовать здесь функцию? Тоесть вместо "d:/Результаты/names.ini" чтобы был путь на рабочий стол.

Comment: хардкодить пути в папку снаружи папки с программой это дурной тон

Comment: @RomanKhvalko, добавил, пример